# Animated Node error on expo go that only happens on android phone

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-navigation

When i open my project with expo go on my android phone it returns this error: "Animated node with tag 1 does not exists". I have no clue about how to fix this, but i found some hints:

1 - It ONLY CRASHES on my android phone, it works fine with my ipad(expo go too) or web.

2 - Appears to have some relation to the stack navigator:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import SignIn from '../pages/SignIn/index';

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();

const AuthRoutes = () => {
    return(
    <AuthStack.Navigator>
        <AuthStack.Screen name="Sign In" component={SignIn}/>
    </AuthStack.Navigator>)
};

export default AuthRoutes;
```

If i just call the SignIn(just a form) component on my  App.js this crash wont happen. Am I missing something about the use of stack navigator on expo? There is something missing on the android folder?

[Here is a print of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWlXc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error I reinstalled the react-navigation modules:

```
npm install @react-navigation/stack
```

It worked for me so I hope it helps
you can also try this maybe:

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. I just started learning about react native application and the app was working fine on chrome but when i try running it on the android device it was giving me the same error.
Searching for quite some time i found that when you run this:

```
npm install https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.4.tar.gz
```

will solve the issue and app is now running.

before installing this package my react-native version was `0.64.0` but now its
this one: `"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.4.tar.gz"`. I think its old archive version.
Also this error accured when i started using [reactnavigation v5](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation) So may be the navigation is not compatible with Expo?? don't know much but it sove the issue for me.